# Working example of Angular 2.0 Material MdDialog with Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I'm working on a POC app, and I'm trying to get the `MdDialog` component working. Does anyone have a working example of what to pass to the `MdDialog` open method?

Angular 2.0: 
https://github.com/angular/angular

Angular 2 Material: 
https://github.com/angular/material2

Comment: All possible dialogs in here https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog codepen example here http://codepen.io/cyrilcherian/pen/GoJeom

Comment: I'm looking for examples using Angular 2.0 Material with Angular 2.0.
https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular2_material

Comment: did you find one ?

Comment: Links are outdated.

Answer (score 69):

### Update to angular v4 and @angular/material 2.0.0-beta.12

`md` prefix was changed to `mat`

Import `MatDialogModule` instead of `MdDialogModule`

`@angular/material` now depends on `@angular/cdk` as a peer dependency.

**Recap**: [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/3eSX2rgaHyx86HaVfnR5?p=preview)

**8 steps to Material Dialog + Appendix**

**Step 1:**
Install package

```
npm i --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```

**Step 2:**
Configure `systemjs.config.js`

```js
map: {
  ...
  '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
  '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
  '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk/a11y': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-a11y.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk/bidi': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-bidi.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk/coercion': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-coercion.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk/collections': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-collections.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk/keycodes': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-keycodes.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk/observers': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-observers.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk/overlay': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-overlay.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk/platform': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-platform.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk/portal': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-portal.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk/rxjs': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-rxjs.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk/scrolling': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-scrolling.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk/table': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-table.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk/stepper': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-stepper.umd.js',
},
```

**Step 3:**
Import `MatDialogModule` to your module

```ts
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, <== required
    MatDialogModule <== here
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Step 4:**
Create desired dialog component like:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'your-dialog-selector',
  template: `
  <h2>Hi! I am modal dialog!</h2>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="dialogRef.close()">Close dialog</button>`
})
export class DialogComponent {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogComponent>) { }
}
```

**Step 5:**
Add the component from step 4 to `declarations` and `entryComponents` arrays of your NgModule decorator:

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, MatDialogModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, DialogComponent ],
  entryComponents: [ DialogComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Step 6:**
Use it in your component:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">Open dialog</button>`,
})
export class App {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openDialog(key) {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
  }
}
```

**Step 7**
Pick out the desired theme:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css" 
  rel="stylesheet">
```

Other themes you can find [here](https://github.com/angular/material2-builds/tree/master/prebuilt-themes)

**Step 8**

If you want to pass data to modal then use the following ([Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/n185tQbEHg1xGlNCAdxQ?p=preview)):

```ts
dialogRef.componentInstance.param1 = "test value";
```

**Appendix**

Routed Dialog: [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6o8UrUwfLIEHBUa3IaBB?p=preview)

Draggable Dialog ([How can i make a MatDialog draggable / Angular Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510888/how-can-i-make-a-matdialog-draggable-angular-material))

---

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/3eSX2rgaHyx86HaVfnR5?p=preview)**

See also

- [Material.Angular.io > Guides > Getting Started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)
- [Master builds](https://github.com/angular/material2-builds)

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a lot of time. I found I also had to add the dialog to 'declarations' in the NgModule for it to work (the plunker does that as well). Also you can send a result into dialogRef.close() and access it in the observable subscription function. Which is useful for confirmation dialogs, etc.

Comment: Can i pass value to the Dialog Component as well?

Comment: @Sumit Agarwal see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826073/pass-parameter-to-mddialog-in-angular-material-2

Comment: Can we avoid the usage of a service class?

Comment: @Sumit Agarwal https://plnkr.co/edit/n185tQbEHg1xGlNCAdxQ?p=preview See line `this.dialogRef.componentInstance.param1 = "test value";`

Comment: Hello, I followed all your above steps but getting this error.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
index.html:25 Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found  
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:398
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:165
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:593

Comment: is there a way to still use reactive forms instead of `#howmuch` syntax with this?

Comment: it works, but injecting mddialogref makes this component untestable

Comment: @bartosz.baczek Can you provide a plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @yurzui, I'll make separate question for that.

Comment: sorry, I'm not able to plunker it :(