# Angular 2: Set @Input variables in Dialog Component

Tags: angular, angular2-material

As per the latest Angular2-Material docs of  [Dialog Component](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/dialog/README.md) . There is no description on how to pass values to dialog component. Is it achievable via component interaction mechanisms? Apart from using a service.

In normal component interaction we had seen that we can pass the values this way:

```
<app-child [data]="some_data"></app-child>

@Input data:string;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Answer in a comment discussion:

this.dialogRef.componentInstance.param1 = "test value";

See Also: [Working example of Angular 2.0 Material MdDialog with Angular 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205593/working-example-of-angular-2-0-material-mddialog-with-angular-2-0/40185852?noredirect=1#comment68946258_40185852)

[plnkr.co/edit/n185tQbEHg1xGlNCAdxQ?p=preview](http://%20plnkr.co/edit/n185tQbEHg1xGlNCAdxQ?p=preview)