# Angular 2 with Material 2: Dialog exception

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to implement Material 2 (v2.0.0-beta.1) dialogs in my Angular 2 (v2.4.3) app.

This is my dialog component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'myproject-confirm',
  templateUrl: './confirm.component.html',
})
export class ConfirmDialog {

    constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ConfirmDialog>) {}

}
```

And it's HTML only contains:

```
This is a test dialog
```

In the component where I want to use this dialog, I am doing this:

```
import { ConfirmDialog } from './confirm.component';

constructor(private _dialog: MdDialog) {}
```

And then I try to open the dialog like this:

```
let dialogRef = this._dialog.open(ConfirmDialog);
```

But this produces the following exception:

> EXCEPTION: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only
>   a getter

I used [Materials official documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog) as an reference for this, and the only thing they are doing different under "Examples" there is injecting `MdDialog` as public instead of private. Hence, I tried changing it into public but still get the same error.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Downgrade your zonejs library and then you will see the origin error

Comment: I have tried using both `0.7.4` and `0.7.2` but I get the same error on both.

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205593/working-example-of-angular-2-0-material-mddialog-with-angular-2-0/40185852#40185852?

Comment: Thank you sir! Following your guide I managed to get it working.