# How to get some dynamic values from component to material2 dialog

Tags: angular, typescript

In the homeComponent.ts am displaying some data from the database. 
In each of this displayed items, I provide a button for the openDailog().

What I want to do now is get the data value of the clicked item in the material2 dialog.

Here is my homeComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-homecomponent',
  template: `
      <app-homecard
        *ngFor="let item of items"
        [item]="item"
        (checked)="onItemChecked($event)"
           >
       </app-homecard>
  `
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
ngOnInit() {
   this.statusService.getStatus()
    .subscribe(items => { this.items = items;});
  }

}
```

And here is the homecard where the Dialog is implemented  from.

```
  @Component({
      selector: 'app-homecard',
      template: `
         <md-card>
            <button md-button (click)="openDialog()"><i class="fa fa-share-alt-square fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> 
        </md-card>
      `
    })
    export class HomeCard implements OnInit {
    @Input() item = {};
    @Output() checked = new EventEmitter();
      constructor(
        private _dialog: MdDialog
        ) { }

    openDialog() {
        let dialogRef = this._dialog.open(DialogShare);
      }
    }

//Dialog component!
    @Component({
      template: `
        <app-sharecard></app-sharecard>
      `,
    })
    export class DialogShare {
      constructor(@Optional() public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogShare>) { }
    }
```

Here is the sharecard where I want to get the item values like `{{item.id}}`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sharecard',
  template: `
  <div  class="shareform">
    {{item.id}}
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
  `
})
export class ShareCard implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  close() {
      this._dialog.closeAll();
  }
}
```

How can I get opened item data in sharecard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly add `item` input to your `ShareCard` component

```
export class ShareCard implements OnInit {
  @Input() item: any;
}
```

then modify `DialogShare` like:

```
@Component({
  template: `<app-sharecard [item]="item"></app-sharecard>`
})
export class DialogShare {
  item: any;
  ...
}
```

and finally pass `item` when you're opening dialog:

```
export class HomeCard {
  ...
  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this._dialog.open(DialogShare);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.item = this.item;
  }
}
```

Take a look at **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/3FYb5nsrtVyXfFyfRyTV?p=preview)**

See also

- [Working example of Angular 2.0 Material MdDialog with Angular 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205593/working-example-of-angular-2-0-material-mddialog-with-angular-2-0/40185852#40185852)

Comment: Awesome! Works nicely. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to get the ``item.id`` in the ShareCard component.ts. At the moment I can't do something like  ``console.log(item.id)``; This is not the original just something I would like to accomplish.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in plunker?

Comment: Here is it . The shareComponent https://plnkr.co/edit/3xyItVYxe9Luuu39Psuh?p=preview