# How to send data in Material 2 dialog Angular 2 from 1 component to other

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using a Material 2 dialog, and I am able to get back data on dialog close.

But I am not able to find any solution to send data on dialog with `@Input`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result-example.html',
})
export class DialogResultExample {
  selectedOption: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogResultExampleDialog);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.selectedOption = result;
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogResultExampleDialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogResultExampleDialog>) {}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `componentInstance` property of [MdDialogRef](https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog), as suggested by [yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui) in **Step 8** of the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205593/working-example-of-angular-2-0-material-mddialog-with-angular-2-0).

For example, if you wanted to pass the value *foo* to a variable `param1` in `DialogResultExampleDialog`, you could do the following:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result-example.html',
})
export class DialogResultExample {
  selectedOption: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogResultExampleDialog);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.param1 = "foo";
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.selectedOption = result;
    });
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result-example-dialog.html',
})
  param1: string;

  export class DialogResultExampleDialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogResultExampleDialog>) {}
}
```

Comment: I think param1 goes inside the body of DialogResultExampleDialog, right?

Answer (score 4):

Another way, you can use `MdDialogConfig`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MdDialogConfig} from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result-example.html',
})
export class DialogResultExample {
  selectedOption: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    let config = new MdDialogConfig;
    if (id) {
      config.data = { id: id }
    } else config.data = null;

    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogResultExampleDialog, config);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.selectedOption = result;
    });
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogResultExampleDialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogResultExampleDialog>) {
    if (dialogRef.config.data) {
            // do something...
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a better way (since the data can be configured within the constructor of the Dialog). Thanks!