# How can i a binding between components correctly

Tags: html, angular, typescript, templates, binding

I'm working in a Simple Crud app. When I will a binding(I didn't know if is correct) My child's template is rendered (it's a dialog component), but I want only pass value to the child's variable and it's work, but I don't know if it's a better way. How can i pass value without render my child's template?

My child Component.ts:

```
export class DialogFormUpdateComponent implements OnInit {

  public titleForm!: string;
  public form!: FormGroup;
  equip!: Equipments;
  @Input() Id!: number;


  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogFormUpdateComponent>, private fb: FormBuilder,
    private EquipmentService: EquipmentsService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.Id); // It's receiving Id value

      this.EquipmentService.GetWithId(this.Id).subscribe(result => {
        this.titleForm = "Update Equipment";
        this.form = this.fb.group({
        name: [result.name, [Validators.required]],
        serialNumber: [result.serialNumber, [Validators.required]],
        voltage: [result.voltage, [Validators.required]],
        electricCurrent: [result.electricCurrent, [Validators.required]],
        oil: [result.oil, [Validators.required]],
        date: [result.date, [Validators.required]],
      });
      });


  }

  public SendFormUpdate(): void {

    let newDate: moment.Moment = moment.utc(this.form.value.date).local();
    this.form.value.date = newDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    const equipment: Equipments = this.form.value;

    this.EquipmentService.PutEquipment(equipment).subscribe(result => {

      alert("Equipment was send with success");
      this.form.reset();
      this.dialogRef.close();
    })
  }

  Cancel() {

    this.dialogRef.close();
    this.form.reset();

  }
}
```

Child Template:

```
    <h1 mat-dialog-title>{{titleForm}}</h1>

<div mat-dialog-content>

  <form [formGroup]="form" class="FormClass">
    <mat-form-field >
      <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="name" required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field >
      <mat-label>Serial Number</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="serialNumber" required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Voltage</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="voltage" required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field >
      <mat-label>Electric Current</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="electricCurrent" required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field >
      <mat-label>Oil</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="oil" required>
    </mat-form-field>
      <div fxLayout="row wrap">
        <div fxFlex="50" fxFlexFill fxLayoutAlign="start center">
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill"  >
            <mat-label>Register date</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="date" [matDatepicker]="picker">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>

        </div>
      </div>


  </form>

</div>

<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button type="Submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="SendFormUpdate()" >Submit</button>
  <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="Cancel()" >Cancel</button>

</div>
```

My parent component.ts:

```
 export class EquipmentsComponent implements OnInit {
  ELEMENT_DATA!: Equipments[];
  form: any;
  titleForm!: string;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'serialNumber', 'voltage', 'electricCurrent', 'oil', 'date', 'actions'];
  @Output() equipID: EventEmitter<number>= new EventEmitter<number>();


  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Equipments>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);

    constructor(private EquipmentService: EquipmentsService, public dialog: MatDialog,
    public DialogUpate: MatDialog, public DialogComponentUpdate: DialogFormUpdateComponent) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    //getall on start
      this.EquipmentService.Getall().subscribe(result => {
      this.dataSource.data = result as Equipments[];
    });
  }

  //Open Create Form
  NewEquipemnt(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogFormComponent,{
      minWidth: '300px', disableClose: true

    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
        //get all
        this.EquipmentService.Getall().subscribe(result => {
        this.dataSource.data = result as Equipments[];
        });
    });
  }

//Open Update Form
  public UpdateEquipment(): void
  {

      const dialogRef = this.DialogUpate.open(DialogFormUpdateComponent,{
      minWidth: '300px', disableClose: true

    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
        //get all
        this.EquipmentService.Getall().subscribe(result => {
        this.dataSource.data = result as Equipments[];
        });
    });

  }


}
```

parent template:

```
    <div class="pad-5 ">
  <mat-card  >

    <div >
      <button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="NewEquipemnt()">New Equipment</button>
    </div>

    <h2 class="m-top-10">Equipments Manager<hr/></h2>

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z2 w-100">

  <ng-container class="m-r-10"matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="serialNumber">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Serial Number </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.serialNumber}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="voltage">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Voltage </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.voltage}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="electricCurrent">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Electric Current </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.electricCurrent}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container  matColumnDef="oil">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Oil </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.oil}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Register date </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">


      <button class="pos-l-50 m-r-10" mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="UpdateEquipment()" >Update</button>
      <button  class="pos-l-50" mat-raised-button color="warn">Delete</button>

      <app-dialog-form-update [Id]="element.equipmentsID"></app-dialog-form-update>
    </td>

  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
  </mat-card>

</div>
```

My template:

[Image template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdnD3.png)

Comment: Yeah you really shouldn't need the DialogFormUpdateComponent inside your template at all. MatDialog takes care of that. You can set the Id using a token like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664974/how-to-pass-data-to-dialog-of-angular-material-2

Comment: Another option could be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019285/how-to-send-data-in-material-2-dialog-angular-2-from-1-component-to-other - I think that still works with newer versions as well.

Comment: I got it on the second option, thaks very much