# passing parameter to mat-dialog open method

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material

**Angular 7.1** , 
**AngularMaterial 7.3**

I am trying to call function and pass some value, It prompt following error

> No component factory found for t1. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Although `t1` is included in `entryComponent`. but once remove passing value to fix value it will work.

```
  <button mat-button (click)="openDialog('t1')">T1</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="openDialog('t2')">T2</button>
```

Once I pass value its show the above code.

```
  openDialog(e) {
    console.log(e);
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(e);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
      dialogRef == null
    });
  }

@Component({
  selector: 't1',
  templateUrl: 't1.html',
})
export class t1 {}

@Component({
  selector: 't2',
  templateUrl: 't2.html',
})
export class t2 {}
```

but once I remove the value and fix `dialogRef.open`, it works fine

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(t1);
```

Comment: if `t1` is your component add this in appModule or  supporting Module file in `entryComponents: []` array

Comment: @Abhishek, `t1,t2` is already added in AppModule

Comment: if it is possible to share appModule?

Answer (score 18):

This works for me. You can refer to this link too. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664974/how-to-pass-data-to-dialog-of-angular-material-2/56190131)

You can use `dialogRef.componentInstance.myProperty = 'some data'` to set the data on your component.

You may need something like this:

> ```
> let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
>             disableClose: true,
>         });
> dialogRef.componentInstance.name = 'Sunil';
> ```

Then in your DialogComponent you need to add your name property:

```
public name: string;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<Component>,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
  ) { }


  openDialog(t1) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NameComponent, {
      data: { t1 }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {

  }
```

while retrieving in dialog component

```
 @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

You should send a variable instead of string. it should be `t1` instead of `'t1'`

```
  <button mat-button (click)="openDialog(t1)">T1</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="openDialog(t2)">T2</button>
```

In your component.ts, you should declare the components

```
public t1 = new t1();
public t2 = new t2();
```

or you can try the below method using `template variables`

```
  <t1 #test1></t1>
  <t2 #test2></t2>
  <button mat-button (click)="openDialog(test1)">T1</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="openDialog(test2)">T2</button>
```

Comment: do you have that instance of t1 in your component.ts

Comment: i have updated my answer, you should get reference to your compnent class name in a property

Comment: after declaring t1,t2, getttin this error `No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

Comment: you can try another method i have suggested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189244/discussion-between-faisaljanjua-and-bear-nithi).

Answer (score 0):

```
openDialog(dialog : string) {
    if(dialog == "t1"){
     const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(t1,{ data: { "YOURVALUE" }});
     dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => { this.YOURVALUE = result; });
    }
    else {
     const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(t2,{ data: { "YOURVALUE" }});
     dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => { this.YOURVALUE = result; });
    }
}
```

Comment: I though about this, but if in case of increase more buttons then like this `<button mat-button (click)="openDialog('t1')">T1</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="openDialog('t2')">T2</button> <button mat-button (click)="openDialog('t3')">T3</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="openDialog('t4')">T4</button>`