# How does Angular Material Dialog "Data" work?

Tags: angular

At the moment I have a `Container` Component which has a list of dynamic components. Each dynamic component has a `@Input() config` property. And the `Container` will process an array with a switch that looks maybe similar to this for a `TextComponent`

```
switch (config.selector) {
    case ComponentTypes.TEXT:
         const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TextContentComponent);
         const componentReference = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
         const component = componentReference.instance;
         component.config = config;
         component.detectChanges();
         return componentReference;
    break;
}
```

When I was looking for how to put my `Container` into a `MatDialog`, I found this [excellent answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664974/how-to-pass-data-to-dialog-of-angular-material-2/45950972#45950972)

To dig into that answer a little:

This method is taking a component `someComponent`.  (Which could be my `Container`). But the second argument seems to be like my `config`.

```
this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(someComponent, {
  width: 330px,
  height: 400px,
  data: {
    dataKey: yourData
  }
});
```

Where this is interesting though is in `someComponent`.

```
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';


constructor(
   @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  // will log the entire data object
  console.log(this.data)
}
```

**Questions**

1. What is going on there? It seems an unlisted way of creating dynamic components which seems less hassle that the method I am using.
2. I expected an `@Input` property but here they chose to Inject a token. This is almost like `new Container(config)` but undocumented. Why did they not consider data an `@input`?
3. Should I make a `dynamic.create(TextComponent, config)` replacement service for my long winded `Container` switch approach?

PS: The reason I am asking is because `@Input` and `ngOnChanges` that doesn't work with dynamic components can be a pain compared to knowing that the data was there as part of instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

You needn't a @Input, when you write

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
  width: '250px',
  data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
});
//You can use dialogRef.componentInstance to "get" the component
//e.g. if you has a variable in your Component: "anotherVariable"
dialogRef.componentInstance.anotherVariable="hello word"
```

Injecting data, you can give value to "data" when open the dialog

Comment: The key though is how the `data` property becomes an Injectable Token in the implementation of DialogOverviewExampleDialog and is available through the constructor?  Every other dynamic component resource would insist that you need to use `@input`. Having the data provided as an injectable in the constructor seems far superior to the hacky `detectChanges()` stuff that is recommended.