# Pass dynamic object key in mat-dialog angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using mat-dialog of angular material. Here is my code:

```
if(abc_name === name){
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ViewAbcComponent, {
      panelClass: 'full-screen-dialog-container',
      data: {abc_name: this.abcDetails.item1[keyValue]}
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      if(result){}
      console.log("ViewAbcComponent dialog closed", result);
    });
  }
```

In `data:` object I want tp pass dynamic `abc_name` value. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data to dialog of angular material 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664974/how-to-pass-data-to-dialog-of-angular-material-2)

Comment: No. I want to pass dynamic object key while passing data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create subject/BehaviorSubject  in service and  listen
(subscribe) to that subject in your ViewAbcComponent  component. as soon as your data changed you have to update data as `subject.next(data);` and you will get it in component.
Subject example:

```
const subject = new Rx.Subject();
subject.next(1);
subject.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

BehaviorSubject example:

```
const subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(0);
subject.next(1);
subject.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

**Elaborating :** (as per request)

1.You have to add varible in your service lets say **app.service.ts**  and add update method.

```
const subject = new Rx.Subject();

  updateSubject(data){
   subject.next(data)
  }
```

2. in whichever component your data is changing you have to call this updateSubject method to update data.
   like `this.appService.updateSubject(updatedData);`
3. In **ViewAbcComponent**   component you have subscribe it like

   `this.appService.subject.subscribe(x => console.log("mydata",x));`

Comment: Can you please elaborate more

Comment: i have edited my comment.. i hope it will clear your doubts?

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. I just want to pass this data: {abc_name: this.abcDetails.item1[keyValue]} when I open dialog box, where abc_name is not just string, it has value. I want that key value on dialog.