# How to pass data to Angular Material Dialog (Angular 14.1)?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664974/how-to-pass-data-to-dialog-of-angular-material-2) but I could not solve my problem.

I have a table on my page. When I double click each row, an **Angular Materia Dialog** is shown and the corresponding row data are loaded to that dialog. The followings are variable in the main `ts` file:

```
eqId: string = '';

onDoubleClick(e: any): void {
    this.eqId = e.rowData["EquipmentId"];
    this.openDialog();
  }
openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EquipmentDetailComponent);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
}
```

The `EquipmentDetailComponent`'s `ts` file is:

```
@Input() eqId: string = '';
```

But when I run, `eqId` is empty in the dialog.
How can I pass data to **Angular Material Dialog**?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass any data by providing a second parameter in the `this.dialog.open()` method like this:

```
eqId: string = '';

onDoubleClick(e: any): void {
    this.eqId = e.rowData["EquipmentId"];
    this.openDialog();
  }
openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EquipmentDetailComponent,
        {eqId: this.eqId}
    );
 
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
}
```

In the `EquipmentDetailComponent` you should inject `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` like this:

```js
export class EquipmentDetailComponent {
...
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {eqId: string}){
    //you can get an access to passed value like this
    console.log(this.data.eqId);
  }
...
}
```