# Dialog Reading an especific route on Angular

Tags: angular, material-ui, routes, dialog

I want to edit some data using dialogs, I can do it moving it to a component, it reads its data and I can edit.
Since the ammount of info that I want to change is small I dind't want an entire page just for that, so I've decide to use dialogs from material.

The part that I'm struggling with is making the dialog be indentified as a route, not as simple dialog. I've done some research but the information that I've found is from old angular versions, and something must've changed that whenever I try to replicate lots of erros pop up.

Is there any document on this, or maybe angular made it simpler in any way?

For now i'm using something like this

```
<a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="['cadastrar', dinamica.id]">
```

but I've wanted to use it

```
<a mat-icon-button (click)="openDialog()">
```

and then add the routing into this:

```
{path:'cadastrarDinamica/cadastrar/:id', component:CadastroDinamicaComponent, canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
```

I've followed this video but it dind't work, some of the tools that he used just created tons of errors

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sk5jOAGl20o

Comment: If you want it to be simple, why are you making it complicated? Just open the dialog and use it, why do you even need routes?

Comment: Because the dialog doesn't read the informations coming from the ids, i want it to edit based on the id, using the function openDialog, it simply opens the dialog, i want this to be attached to the id of what i'm opening...So can I pass the id as a parameter in the function openDialog?

Comment: You can pass data quite easily. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664974/how-to-pass-data-to-dialog-of-angular-material-2

Comment: https://www.nerd.vision/post/how-to-pass-data-to-a-matdialog

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/

Comment: I'm gonna share what i've have for now....

Answer (score 0):

This is the html code for the component calling the dialog

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="editar">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Editar</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let dinamica">
                <a mat-icon-button (click)="openDialog()">
                  <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                </a>
              </td>
            </ng-container>
```

the component.ts

```
openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CadastroDinamicaComponent, {
      data: this.dinamica,
      width: '350px',
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }
```

The dialog component

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveDinamica()">
  <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Nome da Dinâmica</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" id="name" [(ngModel)]="dinamica.nome" required name="nome"/>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Descrição da Dinâmica</mat-label>
    <textarea id="description" class="full-width" matInput [(ngModel)]="dinamica.descricao" name="descricao" required rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <section class="buttons">
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" label="Cancelar" class="p-button-text" mat-dialog-close>Cancelar</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" label="Salvar" class="p-button-text" (click)="saveDinamica()" mat-dialog-close>Salvar</button>
  </section>
</form>
```

and my constructor of the dialog:

```
constructor(private dinamicaService: DinamicaService,
    private messageService: MessageService, private route: ActivatedRoute,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dinamica: Dinamica
    ) {
    this.route = route;
    this.dinamicaService = dinamicaService;
    this.dinamica = dinamica;
  }
```

And the thing is, in my html component as you can see the icon that opens the dialog is within a table. I'm having trouble grabing the data from the row relative to its icon.
I need to read it's Id somewhere but i'm failing in discovering it

Answer (score 0):

Well, i solved the issue.
I was calling it wrong.

in the end it's like this

The HTML calling the dialog:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let dinamica">
                <a mat-icon-button (click)="openDialog(dinamica)">
                  <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                </a>
              </td>
```

The component ts:

```
openDialog(dinamica: Dinamica): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CadastroDinamicaComponent, {
      data: dinamica,
      width: '350px',
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }
```

Removed the ngForm and form, wans't necessary for my problem

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Nome da Dinâmica</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" id="name" [(ngModel)]="dinamica.nome" required name="nome"/>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Descrição da Dinâmica</mat-label>
    <textarea id="description" class="full-width" matInput [(ngModel)]="dinamica.descricao" name="descricao" required rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <section class="buttons">
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" label="Cancelar" class="p-button-text" mat-dialog-close>Cancelar</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" label="Salvar" class="p-button-text" (click)="saveDinamica()" mat-dialog-close>Salvar</button>
  </section>
</form>
```

and the injection is correct.
Since I'm begining at this, sometimes I think that things are more complex then they realy are, and solutions are quite simple in the end.
Need to change the way I'm looking into this stuff to improve