# pass string or object to angular2 material Dialog component

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How to I pass to an angular2 material dialogue component?

Here is the html to trigger:

```
<button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog('stupid')">ADD GIT HOST</button>
```

Here is the TS:

```
openDialog(slug){


    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogGitHost);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      //this.selectedOption = result;
    });

  }
```

How do I pass slug to the dialog on open so I can use it?
e.g.

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogGitHost,slug);
```

Comment: See step8 from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205593/working-example-of-angular-2-0-material-mddialog-with-angular-2-0/40185852#40185852

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass data like this:

```
openDialog(slug){
this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
  disableClose: false,
  data: slug
});
```

and in the DialogComponent you reseive the data with:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.data = this.dialogRef.config.data;
}
```