# Not able to run angular 2 material plunker example

Tags: angular, angular-material2, plunker

I am trying to follow the https://material.angular.io/components link to learn some material concepts. However when I am running their examples on plunker i keep getting an error:

[image]

The exapmles used to work just fine a week before but why this error now.

Comment: Check plunker from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205593/working-example-of-angular-2-0-material-mddialog-with-angular-2-0/40185852#40185852

Answer (score 0):

First, go back to the documentation page you were reading and hard-refresh (SHIFT + reload or clear your cache).  The documentation caches aggressively and doesn't show the latest API; this is [a known issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7660) and you can easily wind up looking at old code that doesn't work anymore.

Second, check your adblocker.  Mine was stopping a request for `pubfig` (?) that resulted in the same error you're seeing above.