# Angular 4 - pass variable from child to parent in a dialog?

Tags: angular, dialog, mddialog, angular-reactive-forms

I have a parent component which opens a child component in a dialog box:

```
open() {
        this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ItemComponent);

        this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {

            this.dialogRef = null;
        });
    }
```

How can I use a variable that is defined and used/modified in the child component to be passed to the parent component?

Comment: See **Step8** from  the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205593/working-example-of-angular-2-0-material-mddialog-with-angular-2-0/40185852#40185852

Comment: Here's a plnkr link that solves your issue (and mine) [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/KbE3uQi2zMNaZlZEEG5Z?p=info) . All credit goes to Thomas pink. Refer this discussion thread [link](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3593) . Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is relate to Angular's **[Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)**

At this case, your can use `@Output()` in your child component:

*child.component.ts*

```
@Ouput() childForm = new EventEmitter();

constructor() {
}

someFunction() {
  this.childForm.emit('some data variable')
}
```

*parenet.component.html*

```
<child-component (childForm)="getDataFromChild($event)"></child-component>
```

*parent.component.ts*

```
public getDataFromChild(event: Event) {
  if (event) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Sir, you made a mistake

`<child-component (output)="getDataFromChild($event)"></child-component>`

Comment: What was the error?  I'm getting issues when trying this out :(